# Django ORM Number of books per author

Tags: python, django, orm

```
class Author(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   age = models.IntegerField()
   friends = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True)

class Publisher(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
   num_awards = models.IntegerField()

class Book(models.Model):
   isbn = models.CharField(max_length=9)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
   pages = models.IntegerField()
   price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
   rating = models.FloatField()
   authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
   publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
   pubdate = models.DateField()

class Store(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
   books = models.ManyToManyField(Book)
```

I am looking to find out that how many books are registed against a author.
Let say, i have Author A1, A2, A3.

`One book may belong from multiple authors.`
I have books, B1, B2, B3

I want to know how many Author A1's books. let say he belong from 2 books.

### Tried already

```
Author.objects.all()
Books.objects.filter(authors=43).count()
2
```

### Which one is better?

```
for auth in authors:
  book.count =book.book_auths.count()
  book_counts_alternative_way = Book.objects.annotate(num_count=Count('book_auths')).filter(book_auths=tech, num_count__gt=0)
```

Any other much efficient way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give related_name to

```
authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author, related_name='book_auths')
```

Then

```
author = Author.objects.get(id=43)
auth_books = author.book_auths.all()

#auth_books are all books which belong to one author
```

Or

```
author = Author.objects.get(id=43)  
books = Book.objects.filter(author=author)
```

Will give all books where the author is the given one.

Or if you want to know for all authors

```
authors = Authors.objects.all()
books = Book.objects.filter(author__in=(x for x in authors))
```

Gives you all books which have authors who exist in db.

To know how many: just attach .count() to result queryset.

Comment: Is there anyway to get all counts? like i do not want to filter the autohor on the name or id. just want to get counts for all.

Comment: @Jack yep, just add ``.count()`` to the end of filter. like ``auth_books = author.book_auths.count()`` or ``books = Book.objects.filter(author=author).count()``

Answer (score 4):

All django objects have a built-in reverse relationship, so you can go "backwards" and "forwards". This means, that once you have an author, you can do this:

```
a = Author.objects.get(name='A1 Author')
a.book_set.count()
```

To get counts for all authors:

```
for a in Author.objects.all():
   print('Author: {} - Number of Books: {}'.format(a, a.book_set.count()))
```

Comment: Is there anyway to get all counts? like i do not want to filter the autohor on the name or id. just want to get counts for all.

Answer (score 1):

Heres the simple solution:

```
Author.objects.annotate(count=Count('book_set'))
```

And then u can iterate it and call "count" as property. [More](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add) about "book_set"